# Front controller rewrite htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, front-controller

I'm using a front controller to handle requests on a web page about buildings.

With this URL I get a list of all buildings on the web page (Note that the word buildings with a S in the end):

```
/buildings
```

And with this URL I show a single selected building from the web page above (Note the word building without any S in the end):

```
/building/building-name
```

My question is if it's possible to also use a URL like this for a single selected building:

```
/buildings/building-name
```

I would like to use `/buildings/` for the page to list all buildings and `/buildings/building-name` for the page to show the selected building. If this is possible, I wonder how I handle this in the htaccess file and in the PHP front controller? If I'm using `buildings` twice as an option in the switch case it would not work?!

Part of the htaccess file:

```
# Buildings (List all buildings)
RewriteRule ^buildings$ /?p=buildings [L,QSA]

#Building + id (Show a single selected building)
RewriteRule ^building/(.+)$ /?p=building&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

PHP-code in index.php:

```
// pagecontrol
$page = isset($_GET["p"]) ? $_GET["p"] : "start";

switch($page) 
{
case 'start':                       require_once('start.php'); break;
case 'buildings':                   require_once('buildings.php'); break;
case 'building':                    require_once('building.php'); break;
default:                            require_once('start.php'); break;
}
```

Preciate some help to solve this problem!

Comment: Just change your 2nd rewrite rule to `^buildings/(.+)$`, nothing else required?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for your comment, but this is not working! How do I handle the switch-case if I have two buildings options with the same name going to two different PHP-pages?

Comment: ? That would only happen if you change both the pattern (which I described above) **and** the parameter you pass to your controller, right?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm not sure how this is working! But it's working as I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: The rewrite rule has 2 parts - a URI pattern to match, and what to do with it.  All you want to do is change the pattern, so it works for `buildings` instead of `building`.  If you do that, but leave the 2nd part (the parameters you pass to your controller) alone, it works just as before but for a different pattern.

Comment: @Don'tPanic OK, so the only thing I needed to do was only to add a S in the second row of the htaccess file and just keep it as it is in the htaccess file then? And in the switch-case I just leave it as it was from the beginning, right?

Comment: My very first comment shows everything you need to do :-)